# Power Query Not loading Redirect site for login

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to build a connector using the power query SDK.  I am using the below code but when I run the project and select 'log in' a blank browser window pops up and not the login screen.  Any reason why I would be getting a blank page?  The redirects are correct but it still displays a blank page.  Why would I be getting a blank page and is there a better way to create this connector to get data out of an API?

[image]

```
[DataSource.Kind="App2", Publish="App2.Publish"]
shared App2.Contents = (optional url as text) =>
    let
        source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url))
    in
        source;

// Data Source Kind description
App2 = [
    Authentication = [
        OAuth = [
            StartLogin = StartLogin,
            FinishLogin = FinishLogin
        ]
    ],
    Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel")
];

StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>
    let
            AuthorizeUrl = "https://APIURL.com/oauth/v1/authorize" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
            client_id = "QmJRpS86dghC2OJHWs2XdVVFTBCffOPe",
            scope = "Read",
            state = state,
            redirect_uri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html"
        ])
    in
        [
            LoginUri = AuthorizeUrl,
            CallbackUri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html",
            WindowHeight = 800,
            WindowWidth = 800,
            Context = null
        ];

FinishLogin = (context, callbackUri, state) =>
    let
        Parts = Uri.Parts(callbackUri)[Query]
    in
        TokenMethod(Parts[code]);

TokenMethod = (code) =>
    let
        Response = Web.Contents("https://APIURL.com/oauth/v1/token", [
            Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString([
                client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
                code = code,
                redirect_uri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html"
            ])),
            Headers = [
                #"Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                #"Accept" = "application/json"
            ]
        ]),
        Parts = Json.Document(Response)
    in
        Parts;

// Data Source UI publishing description
App2.Publish = [
    Beta = true,
    Category = "Other",
    ButtonText = { Extension.LoadString("ButtonTitle"), Extension.LoadString("ButtonHelp") },
    LearnMoreUrl = "https://powerbi.microsoft.com/",
    SourceImage = App2.Icons,
    SourceTypeImage = App2.Icons
];

App2.Icons = [
    Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("App216.png"), Extension.Contents("App220.png"), Extension.Contents("App224.png"), Extension.Contents("App232.png") },
    Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("App232.png"), Extension.Contents("App240.png"), Extension.Contents("App248.png"), Extension.Contents("App264.png") }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `?` at the end of your Authorization URL. It should look like:

```
  AuthorizeUrl = "https://APIURL.com/oauth/v1/authorize?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
                client_id = "QmJRpS86dghC2OJHWs2XdVVFTBCffOPe",
                scope = "Read",
                state = state,
                redirect_uri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html"
            ])
```

You also may want to verify that the Authorization URL webpage is compatible with IE. The [Github sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/samples/github/readme) mentions that you have to do some workarounds with first running the mez file in PowerBI before being able to authenticate in Visual Studio.